# outpointing (to point out an error or errors)

Tags: word-choice

I'm hearing (and seeing in print) the word "outpointing" used a lot lately to mean "pointing out an error."

Example: "Thanks for outpointing. The error has been corrected."

I thought "outpointing" was strictly used to mean "to score more points than one's opponent."

Is it okay to use it to mean "to point out an error", as in "Thanks for outpointing"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to be a revival. I can find only:

> In yonder Wood. (Which with her finger shee Out-poynting)..Yuanished into some other place.

That's from 1595, and the OED lists it as obsolete. It's also literal, rather than figurative, as in actually pointing with a finger in a physical direction.

New words of course enter the language all the time. This one sounds quite business-ese, and rather uncouth, though that's a subjective opinion. I'd avoid it myself until such a time as it becomes more established (and probably I'd avoid it even then, but then it would be a matter of taste).

Answer (score 0):

Of the 19 dictionaries listed in the [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=lemma3&w=outpoint) portal, virtually all of them list two definitions for **outpoint**, in substance

> 1. to score more points than
> 2. (nautical) to sail closer to the wind (point higher) than (another sailing vessel)

Not a single listed source gives a definition close to the usage you suggest.

However, you may be experiencing an emerging trend. Or it may be a quirk. Anyone is free to craft a neologism and see if it takes.

Comment: Yeah, I checked Onelook too and discovered the same thing. Some random Google searches attest to its usage as "pointing out a blunder."

Comment: @whippoorwill it would help if you link to one or two of the examples or at least quote in context.

Comment: Just curious whether anyone else on this forum has heard or seen it used this way.

Comment: From replies given by AP editor Dave Minthorn: Q. Entries on Ottawa and Canada give contradictory instruction for Ottawa as a dateline city. – from Arlington, Va. on Tue, Jun 15, 2010
A. that was fixed. thanks for outpointing.

Comment: Q. David - This is not a question. The entry for volleyball is incorrect. The college sets are now 25 with the 5th set to 15 if needed. You may want to research and change. – from San Angelo, TX on Fri, Feb 06, 2009
A. Thanks for outpointing. We're fixing that entry.

Comment: Q. Webster's New World shows write-down (in the business sense -- the bank took a write-down) as hyphenated. Many AP stories are spelling it as one word. Is there an unlisted exception for it? – from Camarillo, Calif. on Mon, Jan 14, 2008
A. AP stories should be using write-down (hyphenated). Staffers are being reminded. Thanks for outpointing.

Comment: A. Yes, it should be comprises the ... or composed of. Correcting the archived version. Thanks for outpointing.

Comment: @whippoorwill I think if you edit your original question and move these examples to that, it will ensure that people reading the post get the full picture. You could insert a *Supplement* section. Sometimes not all comments are read.

Comment: I'm just waiting for 'outpointage' and 'outpointageness' showing up in sports reporting.